# ASP.NET WebRequest to Highcharts export server

Tags: highcharts, export, webrequest

I have the need to include a highcharts chart in a PDF report. But how can I get the image/png generated by the export.highcharts.com ?
That's what I have done so far:

At a button click, this ajax request is fired:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "Home/Teste",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "html",
   data: { svgParam: myChart.getSVG() },
   success: function (data) {
       doStuff(data);
}});
```

At the server, I get the request and handle as follow:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void Teste(string svgParam)
{
    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://export.highcharts.com/");
    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST";

    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
    string postData = string.Format("filename={0}&type={1}&width={2}&sgv={3}", "chart", "image/png", 1270, Server.UrlEncode(svgParam));

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; multipart/form-data";

    //User agent is based in a normal export.js request
    request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0";

    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    //This is here just to read the response.
    string msg;
    using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        msg = sReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

The svgParam is an html string with content like this: "

I get this svgParam in the asp.net with no problems. But the response from the export.highcharts.com is always the same, as if te svg was not sent:

```
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <a href="http://www.highcharts.com" title="Highcharts Home Page"
            id="logo"><img alt="Highcharts Home Page"
            src="resources/Highcharts-icon-160px.png" border="0"></a>
        <h1>Highcharts Export Server</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="wrap">
        <h3>Oops..,</h3>
        <p>The manadatory svg POST parameter is undefined.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

For the sake of testing, I created another method in my application, to receive this WebRequest as follow:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void Teste2(string filename, string type, string width, string svg)
{
    string whereIsMySvg = svg;
}
```

The filenam, type and width parameters are received. But the svg one is null. I tried to encode, to not encode, serialize as json string, change the content-type...and nothing, the svg parameter never get to the destination.

Any ideas?

Comment: I need same solution. You made that? Can you help me?

Comment: instead of using ajax call and web methods , you can just store SVG in a `hiddenField` then get it on server side

Comment: To avoid such typos I recommend you to use a https://github.com/sochix/highcharts-export-client

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you copied and pasted your code and this is not a typographical error you mispelled "svg" in the request parameters being sent to the exporting server. You have "sgv".